# Dividing people into 3 groups of unknown size

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I have a problem with following task: We have a group of $40$ people, and we want to divide them into $3$ projects with following manner – first and second project has at least $1$ participant and third at least $2$. Find number of ways we can divide them. My main problem is that people are in general distinguishable :)

If they weren't it would be quite simple just solve $x_1+x_2+x_3=40$ where $x_1\ge1$; $x_2\ge1$; $x_3\ge2$. I will be very glad for help.

Comment: To every person you have to assign a value: 1, 2, or 3. So you have to choose a function from the set of 40 people to the set of 3 projects. Now, count how many of those do not satisfy your condition.

Comment: Are the projects also distinguishable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are $3^{40}$ ways of assigning people to projects with no restrictions. Of those, $2^{40}$ assign nobody to project 1 and $2^{40}$ assign nobody to project 2, and $2^{40} + 40 \times 2^{39}$ assign zero or one people to project 3. $1$ assignment leaves projects 1 and 2 short-staffed, $41$ assignments leave projects 2 and 3 short-staffed, and $41$ assignments leave projects 3 and 1 short staffed. By inclusion-exclusion, there are $3^{40} - 3 \times 2^{40} - 40 \times 2^{39} + 83$ possible assignments. Wolfram tells me this is $12\ 157\ 640\ 170\ 289\ 490\ 036$.